# Using Pandas dataframe, how can I highlight cells whose length > 5 on certain columns and output a new column to describe the error?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Given the following dataframe:

```
|  Item Part No 1 |  Item Part No 2 | Random Header |
| --------------- | --------------- | ------------- |
|  abcde          |  abcdefgh       | abcdgef       |
|  abcdefg        |  abcdefgh       | abcdefgh      |
```

How can I achieve the above?

```
|  Item Part No 1 |  Item Part No 2 | Random Header |  Error Message |
| --------------- | --------------- | ------------- |  ------------- |
|  abcde          |  **abcdefgh**   | abcdgef       |  exceed length |
|  **abcdefg**    |  **abcdefgh**   | abcdefgh      |  exceed length |
```

What I have done thus far:

```
df_filtered = df_equipment.filter(regex=("Item Part No"))

def highlight_cells(val, color_if_true, color_if_false):
    color = color_if_true if len(val) > 5 else color_if_false
    return 'background-color: {}'.format(color)

df_coloured = df_filtered.style.applymap(highlight_cells, color_if_true='yellow', color_if_false='#C6E2E9')
```

This does not work so far and how can I grab its index and output a column with the error message?

Comment: Could you expand on how this "does not work so far"? I get expected output on pandas 1.3.2

Comment: Hi @PeterLeimbigler I can only colour the cells, but not create the error message column